# What is char*argv[ ] and how is it similar to char **argv

Tags: c, pointers, command-line-arguments

I am unable to understand how char *argv[] is similar to char **argv.
Also please let me know when to use pointers?

Comment: @Carcigenicate No, it's not an array of arrays. It's a pointer-to-pointers.

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: Do you mean as in the parameters to main? `char*argv[]` means something different when a function parameter, than if it occurred elsewhere.

Answer (score 8):

A function parameter declared as having array type is silently adjusted to having pointer type. Thus, if you declare a function with a parameter of type `int x[]`, the parameter actually has type `int *x`. Similarly, `char *argv[]` in a function parameter is the same as `char **argv` as the array of pointers is adjusted to a pointer to pointer.

Comment: That's not true. An array name is replaced by the address of its 0th element in code generation by the compiler, making equivalent the value of a pointer to an object of a specific type and the name of an array of same type. **But an array and a pointer are 2 diffetent entities!** and remain so. (I'lll not downvote anyway).

Comment: @Frankie_C No, you're wrong. For function parameters, there's a special rule which says that the declarations `T []` and `T *` (and even `T[N]`) are **exactly the same.** That only works with function parameters, though, and FUZxxl didn't assert anything else. So, **his answer is correct.**

Comment: @Frankie_C The rule I describe applies to function parameters, cf. ISO 9899:2011§6.7.6.3/7.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Sorry, but you're wrong. As stated in the  ISO 9899:2011§6.2.5.20 array and pointers are derived types and specifically: 1) An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a
particular member object type, called the element type. (...) 2) A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the
referenced type. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference
to an entity of the referenced type. (...) They are **not the same**, but acts as the same. You are saying that are the same.

Comment: @Frankie_C No, I'm not saying that array and pointers are the same, you don't understand my statement. I'm saying that in function declarations, `T *` and `T[]` mean the same thing.

Comment: @Frankie_C Yes, array and pointer types are not the same. What I say is that a function parameter declared as having array type is adjusted to having pointer type instead. This is a special rule for function parameter and is different from the normal conversion that is going on. Here is an example of this special behaviour: fuz.su/~fuz/src/arrays.c. To cite the section I referenced before: *A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation.*

Comment: @KerrekSB Better this way?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant `T[]` and `T *` are not the same in that context, iff `T` is an incomplete type

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, you are right, I should have added that, but you get the point…

Answer (score 0):

Basically `char * argv[]` is array of char pointers and `char ** argv` is pointer to char pointer.

As we pass it as  *function parameter* `char * argv[]` is adjusted to pointer-type which points to initial element of that array, `char ** argv` and *are both the same things*.

> 6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)
>    ...
>
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation. If the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

As you see we  use both definitions of `main` are equivalent -

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
```

And

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Comment: You *pass* arguments to a function (from the perspective of the caller), but you declare functions to have *parameters* (from the perspective of the callee). This is somewhat of a nitpick but it's important to understand where this decay happens.

Comment: @FUZxxl  Yes , it is important when this _decay_ happens which is not just when passed to functions . But rather _decay_ happens when array is referenced.

Comment: There's no "decay" in the function parameter version. Decay is something that happens to expressions, but this is a declarator. It gets *adjusted*.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Please see the answer .I have edited it.